# Trigger mouse-up programmatically

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to trigger a `mouseup` event programmatically given:

```
<div id="abc">Click me</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        alert('mouseup');
    });
</script>
```

Now, to trigger I've tried the following:

```
document.getElementById('abc').onmouseup();
```

Or with jQuery

```
$('#x').trigger('mouseup');
```

None of these result in an `alert` so I must be doing something wrong here.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cUCWn/85/)

UPDATE: Fixed type with `addEventListener`

Comment: `document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        alert('mouseup');
    });`
It seems you forgot to add the id param in the getElementById func.

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/cUCWn/86/)

Comment: in the code you pasted the id of the element you want to target is missing,  also on your demo you call an ' onmouseup ' method without passing any callback function, if you have a look at the console you can see an error, although the code in your demo works fine without that line of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**getElementById**  doesn't have a call and an argument in the code below.

```
document.getElementById.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    alert('mouseup');
});
```

right example

```
document.getElementById("the id of the element").addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    alert('mouseup');
});
```

and if you want to trigger the event not by the mouse but with code,
there is already an answer in this link 
[How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

`<div id="abc">Click me</div>`

`<script>
    document.getElementById.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        alert('mouseup');
    });
</script>`

getElementById missing the param here i.e **getElementById('abc')**

`document.getElementById('abc').onmouseup();`

onmouseup() is not a function its an Event attributes and should be called on some element.

`$('#x').trigger('mouseup');`

Should be done something like this :

`$( "#abc" ).click(function() {
  $( "#x" ).mouseup();
});`